# R: How to increase the #ram size for #R? / cannot allocate vector of size n Gb

Tags: r, memory, vector, ram

I have a computer with 8GB ram and R giving me the error below?

cannot allocate a vector of size 23.7 GB.

I have tried #memory.limit(size=) but didn't work.

Is there any way to work it out? Thanks

Comment: 23.7 GB is *additional* RAM needed. Also, 8 < 23.7. You need to adjust your code to lower RAM requirements or buy/rent RAM.

Comment: well, as @Roland told you there is not much you can do about the ram conditions short of adding new ram. what you MIGHT be able to do is distributing the workload onto your harddrive with disc.frame: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/disk.frame/versions/0.4.1 - this only works if the chunks you are working with can be read-in/processed bit by bit instead of all at once